# How to catch a floating point error after fpectl has been removed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

Python 3.8.12 [removed the fpectl module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html).
This module enabled catching floating point errors as standard Python exceptions.

I have a Python programme which uses a module which, in turns, calls a closed-source C library.
The C library sometimes causes a floating point error.
In this case, the Python interpreter is killed by the OS and the result is that the programme ends abruptly without leaving a stack trace or without any possibility of recovery.

Because the computations performed by this external C library are optional for my programme, I would like to recover from the floating point error and continue, e.g., by catching an exception.
Before, this was possible with the `fpectl` module:

```py
from external_library import buggy_function
import fpectl

fpectl.turnon_sigfpe()

try:
    buggy_function()
except FloatingPointError:
    print('buggy_function aborted: continuing without it')

fpectl.turnoff_sigfpe()
```

How can I achieve the same result now that `fpectl` is not available any longer?